# How to fully export and import the VPN settings on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, vpn

I discovered the export option from OS X does not export things like: proxies, or DNS settings from the VPN configuration.

How can I export all of these?

Comment: What export option is that?

Comment: When you select a VPN connection in Network Preferences, under the cog, you have the option to Export Configuration.  That export option.

Comment: Would this be of any assistance to you? http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=116582

Comment: @sudorm-rf, your answer looks good - you should post it.

Comment: @JW01: Well, that forum answer wasn't my work.  I guess I could copy it onto here (and give credit), but I wasn't sure if that was the right thing to do.

Comment: @sudorm-rf, it's valuable knowledge that would be added to the community - I think you should go ahead and add it. A lot of of us quote things from the Apple Support KB - same principle. :)

Comment: @JW01: Okay, posted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I found a thread [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=116582) that seems to accomplish what you're asking.  I can't put it any better than forum poster himself, so here's what he said in case the page isn't working:

> I figured out a way to do this, so thought I would post for anyone
>   following me that has a bunch of VPN settings and doesn't want to
>   manually key them back in. You will basically have to copy & paste a
>   few GUIDs to make your old prefs data match your new system. This
>   worked for me going from one Mac OS X 10.6 SL system to another SL
>   system. I would imagine similar steps would work for Mac OS X 10.5
>   Leopard and possibly 10.7 Lion. Here we go:
>
> 1. First, go to Network Preferences on your new machine and add VPN (L2TP), VPN (PPTP), or whatever VPN "interfaces" you need. Do not
>      create any new VPN configurations at this time. Close Network Prefs.
> 2. Open System Profiler, select and copy to the clipboard the Hardware UUID from the Hardware tab.
> 3. Navigate to ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost and find your old NetworkConnections prefs file. It will have the form of
>      com.apple.networkConnect..plist. Make a copy of this
>      file. Replace the  portion w/ the one you copied in
>      step #2. Don't forget to remove any spaces and the " copy" tag. You
>      should now have a new file called
>      com.apple.networkConnect..plist.
> 4. Open 2 files in an editor that can handle .plist files (I used TextWrangler): the com.apple.networkConnect..plist file
>      you just made, and
>      /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist.
> 5. In preferences.plist, look for the GUID of each VPN interface that you've created. The "UserDefinedName" string at the end of the key
>      will tip you off:
>
> `<key>14A4B264-C231-41FE-857B-EE5557B69851</key> <dict> <key>DNS</key>
>   <dict/> <key>IPv4</key> <dict> <key>ConfigMethod</key>
>   <string>PPP</string> </dict> ... <key>UserDefinedName</key>
>   <string>VPN (L2TP)</string> </dict>`
>
> The first long string ("14A4B264...") is the part you need. Copy this
>   to the clipboard.
>
> 1. Now move over to your com.apple.networkConnect file. Find the key that has all of your old VPN settings *for that VPN type* contained
>      w/in it. Select all of the key name (which is the GUID of your VPN
>      interface on your old Mac), then paste to replace it w/ the new GUID.
> 2. Repeat steps 5 & 6 for each VPN interface you need. In my case, there were 2: L2TP and PPTP.
> 3. Save your changes and close the com.apple.networkConnect file. Close the preferences.plist file WITHOUT saving anything.
> 4. Open your Network Preferences, select your VPN interface(s), and you should see your past configurations.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Not finding a `com.apple.networkConnect..plist` or `com.apple.networkConnect..plist` on High Sierra (my old computer) or Mojave (my new one.) . Has it changed?